# How to prevent Android's back gesture from selecting text inside of nested webview?

Tags: android, webview, react-native, gesture

We have an app that uses a Webview to render a text editor (`contentEditable`) inside of a React Native application. This works well overall, except that the Android back gesture can lead to changes in the selection of text inside the Webview and similar strange behaviors.

We've tried things like having an element along the screen edge that pops out to overlay the Webview when a user begins a back gesture, tried with both `onPress` and `onPressIn`.

But by that time, it's already too late to `evt.preventDefault()` - and the text selection takes place even though the Webview is now covered by another element, I guess because it's technically still the same event that triggered the overlay. (Also tried `evt.stopPropagation` in desperation.)

Is there any way to prevent text selection within our Webview when a user uses the back gesture?